# Neo4j add properties or attibutes to nodes when you create them

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a node with about five other attributes including name and some characteristics to that node. How would I go about adding those attributes or properties in the create statement

```
CREATE (n {<node-name>:<label-name>})
```

For example if I wanted to create a node for a person I would name it after the person and have attributes name, weight, height, and etc. Is there any way to put all those in one create statement?

Answer (score 7):

The best way to handle this is to use `SET` :

```
CREATE (n:NodeLabel) SET n += $props RETURN n
```

Where `$props` is a parameters map you pass as query parameter.

If you want to do it in the browser, you can do it by just creating the properties one by one :

```
CREATE (n:NodeLabel) SET n.name = "name", n.weight=88, n.height=107 RETURN n
```

Alternatively, you can also set them manually inside the node :

```
CREATE (n:NodeLabel {name:"cool", weight:88}) RETURN n
```

Thirdly, as mentioned by Nicole, you can set directly a map :

```
CREATE n SET n = {name:"Nicole", age:24} RETURN n
```

The Nicole's suggestion makes me think also that you can simulate the parameters using a WITH in upfront :

```
WITH {name:"Nicole",age:24} as params
CREATE n SET n = params
RETURN n
```

Comment: You can also do this in the browser:

`CREATE n SET n = {name:"Nicole", age:24} RETURN n;`

`MATCH n WHERE n.name = "Nicole" SET n += {hair:"blonde", birthday:"1/31/91"} RETURN n;`

Comment: Thx Nicole, true, added your suggestion.